# How to ensure Else statement remains on the same html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, if-statement

Using - HTML, JavaScript, JQueryMobile, Phonegap. (One page architecture, all pages are on one html page)

I have an if/else statement for user login, so the if statement directs the user to the homepage (if user/pass found in the database) which works perfectly fine, however I currently have a notification for the else statement but the issue is that after the notification it redirects the user back to the index page instead of remaining on the same page and allowing the user to try again.

What can I use to prevent the page being reloaded to another page for the else statement? I have already tried event.preventDefault(); and event.stopPropagation(); but I just get an error.

See below my current code -

```
function loginUser()
{
    db = window.openDatabase("SoccerEarth", "2.0", "SoccerEarthDB", 2*1024*1024);
    db.transaction(loginDB, errorCB);
}

function loginDB(tx)
{
    var Username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var Password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM SoccerEarth WHERE UserName='" + Username + "' AND Password= '" + Password + "'", [], renderList);
}

function renderList(tx,results) 
{
    if (results.rows.length > 0) {
        navigator.notification.alert("Login Success!");
        window.location = "#page4";
    }
    else
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        /* navigator.notification.alert("Incorrect! Please try again. "); */
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where is the event object here ?

Comment: In your `else` there's nothing that redirect the page and there is no `event` variable defined (at least in this piece). Maybe it's your `<form>` tag but with the code you share is impossible to see the problem. Ask a correct question reading first the link I've attached in last comment. Good luck!

Comment: At least post the complete event function, no one can help you this way. More effort, please.

Comment: *"but I just get an error"* ***What*** error? **Any** time you find yourself typing "but I get an error" or similar, backspace and type "But I get this error: _______________" (using copy and paste to ensure that you're reporting the error exactly correctly).

Comment: The error I get is '0' from the function below which is just a debug alert I have if something doesn't work regarding the javascript. - 
                         function errorCB(err) {
                             alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
                         }

Comment: I have updated the code to show the complete function. Basically, the if result works perfectly fine in which the user is directed to #page4, however the else is triggered when the user has entered incorrect user/pass and therefore the user should remain on the page to try the user/pass again. The problem is that when the else is triggered, it displays the commented out alert in my code and then takes the user back to the index page rather than remaining on the login page. Do you see the problem?

Comment: the reason i used the event.prevenetDefault(); was because i thought it may stop the page from redirecting the user back to the index page.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function renderList(event, tx, results) {
        if (results.rows.length > 0) {
            window.location = "#page4";
         } else {
           event.preventDefault();
           event.stopPropagation();
          /* navigator.notification.alert("Incorrect! Please try again. "); */
        }
```

You need to pass the event in as a arguement. Then prevent the default behaviour on it by using event.preventDefault();

But I'd like to point out that you aren't using an event here, this is just checking to see if something is on the page.

Comment: I have updated the code to show the complete function. Basically, the if result works perfectly fine in which the user is directed to #page4, however the else is triggered when the user has entered incorrect user/pass and therefore the user should remain on the page to try the user/pass again. The problem is that when the else is triggered, it displays the commented out alert in my code and then takes the user back to the index page rather than remaining on the login page. Do you see the problem?

Comment: the reason i used the event.prevenetDefault(); was because i thought it may stop the page from redirecting the user back to the index page.